# How to format font color of a text inside echo " "

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to ask if how to put tags like `<font>` and have a inline style wherein to color a font

```
<?php
    $member_id = $_SESSION['member_id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id='$member_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $getpic = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = '$member_id'")or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($post); 
        echo "<a href='profiletest.php'>"."<img src='image/members/".$getpic['photo']."'width='20px' height='20px'>"." ".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."</a>";
?>
```

How to format font color in `echo`?

Comment: use `<span>` and/or CSS

Comment: how to insert it sir?

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: @LouchinVarCariasCejar `<span>` is [html](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)

Comment: @Glide it's ok sir! It's for education purposes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` in php is outputing everything you provide in within the quotations as HTML code, so if you have:

`echo "<span style=\"color: #000;\">Something</span>";` 
it will display **Something** with color = #000

Comment: i use something else other than `#000` since generally text is already black.

Comment: Thank you sir :) very helpful! I'll accept this answer but in 8 minutes :))